# Batch file to run java.class and save the output in text file with systemdate

Tags: java, batch-file

I'm trying to execute class file. After that I need the output of the class file in a new text file. Every time I run the batch file the output filename should be: `ClassOutput+SystemDate`.
I mean I'm expecting the text file name is (Classoutput30012012)

```
cd \
cd Abc\JavaApplication
java MyJavaApplication.Class
```

Comment: Is this homework?  Please tag it as such.  You haven't actually asked a question, and frankly, it looks like you are asking someone to do your homework assignment for you.  What have you tried?  What are you having trouble with?  Is this even a Java question?  It seems more like a shell-script question.  In which case, you haven't specified the OS or shell you are using....

Comment: Eric, I'd be very surprised if there is anyone who gives homework assignments to be done in batch files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only guess what you mean here, but let's try anyway:

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined MyDate set "MyDate=%%x"
set MyDate=%MyDate:~0,14%
java -cp \Abc\JavaApplication MyJavaApplication > Classoutput%MyDate% 2>&1
```

Comment: Given the quality and thought behind your question (and the fact that the question doesn't even contain a question mark) I'm not really inclined to elaborate or explain further. I guess you just take the code anyway and not read or learn anything of what I'd write.

Comment: Many thanks Joey but I'm getting text file with (Classoutputx) name but there is no date . I mean I'm expecting Classoutputx30012012

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I forgot to escape a `%`.

Comment: In that case you can accept the answer as the correct one by clicking the checkmark left to it.

Comment: My apologizes @joey I forgot to click the checkmark because I'm new here .